# How to make a website start scrolling from the top but then stop at a certain point when scrolling up

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a website that has a new splash screen and header at the top in its redesign that I want people to see when they load the page. From there, there's a button arrow they can click to jump down to the next section (or they can simply scroll, haven't figured out how to disable the scroll option or if I want to on that button). But once they scroll down to the main page and section, I don't want them to be able to scroll back up past a certain point to see it again (unless the page is refreshed). I came across this fiddle and coding and it seems to work, but it STARTS at the height I wanna stop it up after the initial scroll and am not sure how to get it to START at the top of the page, then stop at that point when scrolling up.

```
<div id="test"><div>
```

```
#test{
    height: 3500px;
    margin-top: 1000px;
}
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var eTop = $("#test").offset().top;
    $(document).scrollTop(eTop);
    var eHeight = $("#test").height();
    var eBottom = eTop + eHeight - $(window).height();
    $(document).on("scroll", function(e){
        var windowScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        if(windowScrollTop < eTop){
            console.log("not allowed");
            $(document).scrollTop(eTop);
        }
        else if(windowScrollTop > eBottom){
            $(document).scrollTop(eBottom);
        }
        else{
            console.log("allowed");
        }
    });
});
```

Though I suppose another potential solution could be in the button itself. After its clicked, to have it scroll and essentially 'lock' the lower part of the page in place (in not letting it scroll back up beyond that point) though I'm not sure how to do that.

```html
<nav role="navigation" class="open">
  <a href="#services" class="banner-btn"><img src="https://pluspng.com/img-png/down-arrow-png-down-icon-1600.png" alt="" height="100" width="100"></a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It not very clear of what you are trying to achieve but in the below snippet added button to enable and disable the scrolling and one for to scroll to the bottom

```js
function func() {
  window.scrollTo({
    top: 4500,
    left: 0,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
};

  function disableScroll() {
    // Get the current page scroll position
    scrollTop =
      window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    scrollLeft =
      window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft,

      // if any scroll is attempted,
      // set this to the previous value
      window.onscroll = function() {
        window.scrollTo(scrollLeft, scrollTop);
      };
  }

function enableScroll() {
  window.onscroll = function() {};
}
```

```css
#test {
  height: 3500px;
  padding-top: 1000px;
}

.btnScroll {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
.btnDisable {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top:0;
}
.btnEnable {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">Tester
  <div>
    <button onclick="func()" class="btnScroll">Scroll</button>
    <button onclick="disableScroll()" class="btnDisable">Disable Scrolling</button>
    <button onclick="enableScroll()" class="btnEnable">Enable Scrolling</button>
```

### Update:

To prevent upper (or back or previous ...something) scrolling when reached on final destination of scroll

```js
function func() {
  window.scrollTo({
    top: 750,
    left: 0
  });

  var previousPosition = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

  window.onscroll = function() {
    var currentPosition = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

    if (currentPosition < 750) {

      window.scrollTo(0, 750);
    }
    previousPosition = currentPosition;

  };
};
```

```css
#test {
  height: 3500px;
  padding-top: 1000px;
}

.btnScroll {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">Tester
  <div>
    <button onclick="func()" class="btnScroll"><img src="https://pluspng.com/img-png/down-arrow-png-down-icon-1600.png" alt="" height="20" width="20"></button>
```

Comment: Hello Rana and thank you for these! That puts a visual and gives me some hints to it. In my edit I suppose I attempted to clarify.

When my users first load the page, there is a downwards arrow button that takes them to the next section. Once they click that I don't want them to be able to scroll back up beyond that (back to the header graphic, etc). Hopefully that clarifies things.

Comment: Thank you Rana! So close! so I'll put this in a fiddle so you can see what I have going on. http://jsfiddle.net/n7BSs/ the issue that I have is when I click on that button, it jumps to the spot it should, PERFECTLY, and you can't scroll up (unless you refresh). Which is perfect. The problem is, they can't scroll to the bottom there unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Sorry rana that linked the wrong fiddle. my fault one moment. **Edited** https://jsfiddle.net/9byfgmjr/

Comment: You forget to change condition of `if` from `3500` to `750` . You only changed the point to scroll at only @RobertEttinger

Comment: genius, can't believe I didn't see that, haha. Thank you Rana! HUGE HELP! (I noticed a little bit of flicker on it but will work on that)

Comment: No worries , happy to help @RobertEttinger . Feel free for any queries related to code